# is n't Arraylist FIFO?

Tags: java, arraylist

I went through [arraylist docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). But i do not find any where in docs or google about being mentioned it as FIFO data structure ?

Until and unless, I do not remove/delete element from list, I will get the elements in same order they are inserted. So can't arraylist

Comment: `ArrayList` is not a data structure that uses head/tail concept, everything is based on index. And yes, iteration order is based on insertion order unless an explicit sort is done.

Comment: `Arraylist` will hold the last element added at the end of the list. So it keeps the order of insertion. But it's a random access container, it doesn't really have a sense of first in first out.

Comment: As a side note, just based on the way that `ArrayList` works internally, it wouldn't be a good idea to use it as a FIFO queue. Removing the element at index 0 causes the entire array to be shifted, i.e. it's an O(n) operation. If `ArrayList` could be used as some kind of a queue, it would be LIFO. (But don't use `ArrayList` as a queue. You'd probably use `ArrayDeque`, or something even more specialized.)

Answer (score 9):

`ArrayList` is random access. You can insert and remove elements anywhere within the list. Yes, you can use this as a FIFO data structure, but it does not strictly enforce this behavior. If you want strict FIFO, then use `Queue` instead.

Comment: Got it. My point is if we do not add/remove element once it is created initially, then it order will be FIFO. Also when I say add/remove , it  means without mention of index explicitly.

Comment: @scottmiles If you are not adding and removing elements calling an ArrayList "FIFO" is meaningless.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's not a `FIFO`, it's backed by an `Array`, and the methods it provided make it act just like an `Array`, you can find them from its source code:

```
/**
 * The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored.
 * The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer. Any
 * empty ArrayList with elementData == DEFAULTCAPACITY_EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA
 * will be expanded to DEFAULT_CAPACITY when the first element is added.
 */
// Android-note: Also accessed from java.util.Collections
transient Object[] elementData; // non-private to simplify nested class access

/**
 * Returns the element at the specified position in this list.
 *
 * @param  index index of the element to return
 * @return the element at the specified position in this list
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E get(int index);

/**
 * Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with
 * the specified element.
 *
 * @param index index of the element to replace
 * @param element element to be stored at the specified position
 * @return the element previously at the specified position
 * @throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E set(int index, E element);

/**
 * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
 *
 * @param e element to be appended to this list
 * @return <tt>true</tt> (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
 */
public boolean add(E e);
```

so the ways you manipulate the data is unlimited, if you want a `FIFO`, consider using a [Queue](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Queue), the `FIFO` feature is provided by the methods (use `ArrayDeque` as an example):

```
/**
 * The array in which the elements of the deque are stored.
 * The capacity of the deque is the length of this array, which is
 * always a power of two. The array is never allowed to become
 * full, except transiently within an addX method where it is
 * resized (see doubleCapacity) immediately upon becoming full,
 * thus avoiding head and tail wrapping around to equal each
 * other.  We also guarantee that all array cells not holding
 * deque elements are always null.
 */
transient Object[] elements; // non-private to simplify nested class access

/**
 * Inserts the specified element at the end of this deque.
 *
 * <p>This method is equivalent to {@link #addLast}.
 *
 * @param e the element to add
 * @return {@code true} (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
 * @throws NullPointerException if the specified element is null
 */
public boolean add(E e);

/**
 * Retrieves and removes the head of the queue represented by this deque.
 *
 * This method differs from {@link #poll poll} only in that it throws an
 * exception if this deque is empty.
 *
 * <p>This method is equivalent to {@link #removeFirst}.
 *
 * @return the head of the queue represented by this deque
 * @throws NoSuchElementException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E remove();

/**
 * Retrieves, but does not remove, the head of the queue represented by
 * this deque.  This method differs from {@link #peek peek} only in
 * that it throws an exception if this deque is empty.
 *
 * <p>This method is equivalent to {@link #getFirst}.
 *
 * @return the head of the queue represented by this deque
 * @throws NoSuchElementException {@inheritDoc}
 */
public E element();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, for FIFO you may want to use `LinkedList` or one of `Queue` implementations.